# Widows 10 background not working

Tags: windows-10, display, desktop-customization, background

I have a windows 10 PC. I recently connected it to two 49" ultrawide monitors and adjusted the resolution under display settings to the appropriate setting. Since the old background I had was set for a standard 23" screen, it was stretched and distorted so I tried to change it. Every time I try to change the background to another picture it just goes to a default black screen.

The only picture it lets me set as the background is that original picture from before, all others just get set to a solid black background.

Not sure why hooking up new screens would affect the ability to set the background?

Answer (score 0):

Ultrawide screens are becoming more and more popular, and it’s no surprise – they look epic. Unfortunately, there’s not a whole lot of resources for wallpapers for ultrawide screens out there.

I found some wallpapers on this site that might work for you
[30 WALLPAPERS THAT WILL LOOK STUNNING ON YOUR ULTRAWIDE DISPLAY](https://theultralinx.com/2018/08/30-wallpapers-that-will-look-stunning-on-your-ultrawide-display/)